# How to take the sum of items from a list from a user input

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, user-input

Im trying to have a user input items that get added to a list and then find the sum of all the items in the list. Of course this would only work with numbers and I would have instructions prompting the user to only enter in numbers, but how do I get the sum of items from a list that comes from user input?

My current code only gets the text that the user input types into the text box and then those items get put into a list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>

    <input type='text' id='input' />
    <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

    <ul id='list'>
      <li> <b>Topics</b></li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("input").value;

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerText = text;


        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to a variable called `sum` and use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to show the sum on the page.

Since the input is a string, use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to turn it into a number so that when you add it to sum, it actually adds and doesn't just add the item to the end of sum.

The snippet below works.

```js
var sum = 0;

document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = text;
  sum += parseInt(text);
  
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <input type='text' id='input' />
  <input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

  <ul id='list'>
    <li> <b>Topics</b></li>
  </ul>
  
  <h3 id="sum">0</h3>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the current sum using the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) attribute and for each new `li` update that attribute.

```
<ul id='list' data-total="0">...</ul>
list.dataset.total = Number(list.dataset.total) + Number(text);
```

```js
let list = document.getElementById("list");
let sum = document.getElementById("sum");
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  let text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = text;
  list.appendChild(li);
  list.dataset.total = Number(list.dataset.total) + Number(text);

  sum.textContent = list.dataset.total;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' value='add to list' id='add' />

<ul id='list' data-total="0">
  <li><b>Topics (<span id='sum'></span>)</b></li>
</ul>
```